# How to make a div move down if mouse hovers over it jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hover, mouse

I'm trying to make a `<div>` that will glide down when the persons mouse hovers over it.  I believe this would be jQuery which I have little experience with.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: i've answered previous questions of this sort using pure css; interested?

Comment: A casual google search would lead you to jQuery's [hover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) method. Or use a css only approach, as @j__m suggests. I'd suggest doing some research, and trying out a few examples on your own. Then, if you experience a problem we can give you more specific advice.

Comment: For this kind of basic movement, use CSS for any real browser, and only use stuff like jQuery for Internet Exploder.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".your-div").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ marginTop: 300 });
})
```

Comment: I changed the your-div to ".tothetop" which tothetop is the name of my div.  And it's not working for me.

Comment: if by name, you mean <div name="tothetop"> then make the selector: $("[name=tothetop]")

Answer (score 1):

```
#example:hover
{
  position: relative; margin-top: 40px;
  animation-name: slide-down; animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes slide-down
{
  from { margin-top: 0px; } to { margin-top: 40px; }
}
```

Fiddle includes the downlevel (-moz and -webkit) styles.  http://jsfiddle.net/b7Hqj/

Answer (score 0):

A little hover that moves an div up/down can be easily done in CSS. Here’s one example:

HTML:

```
<div class="product">
<p> Product Info </p>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.product {
border: 2px solid #999;
padding: 20px;
display: inline-block;
}
.product:hover {
transform: translateY(-15px); /* edit X/Y as per requirements */
}

body {
padding: 50px;
}
```

Woking example: http://jsfiddle.net/pEBw5/